# tatgetSdk=compileSdk=26, but auto-generated XML refers to v28 resource, why?

Tags: android

I have an app that hasn't been updated for many years and I just want to compile it. The only changes I've made was set Gradle to 7.4 (`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip`), upgrade to `androidx` and set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`. The only other dependency is `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`.

Where is the v28 reference coming from, is it from `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2`? Or from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0`? Is there a way to find out what's the most recent version that supports target level 26?